# How to install mysql workbench in debian buster?

Tags: mysql, debian, mysql-workbench

I tried the following commands :

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1debian8_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

but on searching mysql-workbench-community

```
sudo apt-cache search workbench | grep mysql
```

returns nothing.

And

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench-community
```

What to do ?

Answer (score 6):

I did manage to install without issues MySQL Workbench 8.0.19 version from an Ubuntu package in Debian Buster, with the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

First you must [download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) the package from the mysql website:

Just select Ubuntu Linux operating system and 18.04 version (19.10 version had broken dependencies) .

Hope this helps.

Comment: it seems to be working but I got this error: /usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpcrecpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: That worked, but to avoid an error when saving schema's in Buster I needed to add the US locale:
- Uncomment en_US.utf8 in /etc/locale.gen
- Run locale-gen
- Confirm with locale -a and restart MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench mysql-workbench has been removed from Debian buster due to a release-critical bug.

- https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mysql-workbench
- https://tracker.debian.org/news/943250/mysql-workbench-removed-from-testing/
- https://bugs.debian.org/867943
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89898

Comment: Was it removed for good, or is it going to be back someday?

Comment: @LucianoSerra No change yet.

Comment: @LucianoSerra I suppose it will be back futher!

Comment: If you are willing to work with a critical bug, you can download an Ubuntu version from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/. Then from a terminal install it with sudo dpkg -i. Then you need to open synaptic package manager which will notice the broken package. Use Edit > Fix Broken Package, then Apply the changes. Workbench will not load for you with a WARNING. So be careful how much you count on it. An alternative I've used is dbeaver.

Comment: As stated here (https://bugs.debian.org/867943) the 'critical bug' has been resolved a long time ago...

Comment: @Gianks It is true. But it was not released by the Debian team or the MySQL team. Anyway, it is "always" possible to install as posted above!

Answer (score 2):

It can also be installed from Snapcraft. I haven't used it that much, but apparently it works. First you need to enable snapd:

> $ sudo apt update

> $ sudo apt install snapd

> $ sudo snap install core

Then install MySQL workbench (community edition):

> $ sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community

If you want to delete it, simply:

> $ sudo snap remove mysql-workbench-community

Comment: Do anyone knows if there are any issues with this method?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the latest version of MySQL Workbench (as of this writing) on Debian 10 using this method:

```
sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.10_amd64.deb
```

A couple dependencies were missing so I subsequently ran:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Just started using it, but MySQL Workbench seems to be running fine. It's also worth mentioning the link below states MySQL Workbench community is not available on Debian, although I'm not sure why this is the case.

> mysql-workbench-community - MySQL Workbench (not available for Debian
> platforms)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-available

Answer (score -1):

Command line to install mysql on Debian 10:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

Remember to make safe passwords with lettler numbers and symbols

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
$ sudo apt-get build-dep mysql-server
$ wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

have a nice coding!